# Prove that there exists a $t \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17})$ such that $t^2-2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)t-1 = 0$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17})$ such that $x^2+y^2 = (2+\sqrt{17})^2$. Prove that there exists a $t \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17})$ such that $$t^2-2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)t-1 = 0.$$

I was wondering about how to go about proving this. Is the condition that $x^2+y^2 = (2+\sqrt{17})^2$ necessary and also could we use the quadratic formula in order to find $t$?

Comment: Try applying the quadratic equation to the polynomial in $t$. In order for it to be solvable over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{17}]$, what is necessary?

Comment: @erfink We have $t = \dfrac{y}{x} \pm \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^2+1}$.

Comment: Good. Now rearrange the radical... I get $t=\frac{y}{x} \pm \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}$

Comment: @erfink Now we have $t = \dfrac{y}{x} \pm \dfrac{2+\sqrt{17}}{x}$.

Comment: Excellent. Given that $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{17}]$, is this expression for $t$ also in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{17}]$ ?

Comment: @erfink Yes, since we can take the conjugate.

Comment: Without the condition the statement isn't true $t^2 - t - 1= 0;x=1, y =2$ would have solutions $(1 \pm \sqrt 5)/2$ which aren't in the the field but $x^2 + y^2 = \ne (2+\sqrt{17})^2$ either .  Yes, use quadratic equation to get the solution in terms of $y, x$ but then show the result is in the field.

Answer (score 1):

$$t^2-2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)t-1 = 0\iff t=\frac{\frac yx\pm\sqrt{(\frac yx)^2+1}}{2}=\frac{y\pm 2+\sqrt{17}}{2x}$$
But $x=a+b\sqrt{17}$ and $y=c+d\sqrt{17}$ so
$$t=\frac{c\pm2+(d+1)\sqrt{17}}{2(a+b\sqrt{17})}=\frac{(c\pm2+(d+1)\sqrt{17})(a-b\sqrt{17})}{2(a^2-17b^2)}=A+B\sqrt{17}$$ where $A$ and $B$ are rational. This proves the statement.